# StackOverflowError in JBoss 7 when trying to explore a hierarchy

Tags: hibernate, jboss, tree, stack-overflow, hierarchy

In my Jboss7 Java EE 6 web application, I need to manage a tree structure of simple "category" entities like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="categorie")
@NamedQueries({ 
    @NamedQuery(name="selezionaTutti", query="select c from Categoria c left join fetch c.children left join fetch c.parent")
})
public class Categoria implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String nome;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private List<Categoria> children = new LinkedList<Categoria>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private Categoria parent;

... //various getter, setter, and so on
}
```

The named query load my whole (little) tree all at a time, the first time, then it stays in the persistence context.

Then I want to "explore" the tree, so I get the root node and pass it to this function:

```
private List<Categoria> getAlberoCategorie(Categoria root, int profondita) {
        List<Categoria> tmpList = new ArrayList<Categoria>();
        root.setProfondita(profondita);
        if ( root.getParent() != null ) {
            tmpList.add(root);
        }
        if (!root.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            profondita++;
            for (Categoria figlia : root.getChildren()) {
                tmpList.addAll(getAlberoCategorie(figlia,profondita)); // this line generates the stack overflow!!! 
            }
        }
        return tmpList;
    }
```

The exact stack trace of the exception is:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>     org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:112)
>     org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:137)
>     org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.isEmpty(PersistentBag.java:249)
>     it.trew.data.CategoriaFacade.getAlberoCategorie(CategoriaFacade.java:59)

In my local machine, all works fine indeed. 
On a small test server, it crashes when reading categories!

How can I improve my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stack space is exceeded. You put too many data on the stack. This can be, because you use too many local variables (local variables are hold on the stack) or because the recursion depth is to deep or infinite.

What you can do: In this order:

1) Check for infinite recursion. This can happen if a categorie entity has itself or its parent or ancestor in its list of children. In this case you get an infinite loop (due to infinite resursion) which breaks when the stack is full whith exactly the exception you've got.

To check this, you look into your database or you debug the code or you print the recursion depth to System.out (you already have the depth in the parameter `profondita`).

If no infinitive loop:

2) tmpList is hold on the stack. Might be, it needs too much space there. Make it as a parameter instead of a return value (is definitively less pretty, but uses less resources):

```
private void getAlberoCategorie(List<Categoria> list, Categoria root, int profondita) {
    root.setProfondita(profondita);
    if ( root.getParent() != null ) {
        list.add(root);
    }
    if (!root.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
        profondita++;
        for (Categoria figlia : root.getChildren()) {
            getAlberoCategorie(list, figlia,profondita); 
        }
    }
}
```

If this still does not help and the depth is very deep but not infinite:

3) Replace the recursion by iteration (common programming technique, but very ugly in this case because this is made for recursion).

Probably 1) (I guess that) or 2) will solve the problem.